# Post form on select with JQuery Datepick

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a calendar I display with only certain dates available and the rest disabled. I get all my dates and make up my calendar and it displays without problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.post('/jreqlib', 
            { Action: 'GetDates',
            }, function(data) {

                var myNewDates = new Array;
                for (var x = 0; x < data['validPubDates'].length; x++) {
                    myNewDates.push(data['validPubDates'][x]);
                }
                var myValidDates = new Array;
                for (var x = 0; x<data['validPubDates'].length; x++) {
                    var theDate = data['validPubDates'][x];
                    myValidDates.push(theDate);
                }               
                $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({
                    multiSelect: 999,
                    minDate : '-14d',
                    maxDate : '+2y',                        
                    onSelect : function (dateText, inst) {
                        //alert("Clicked');
                        //$("#FormId").click();
                        $(this).parent('form').submit();
                    },
                    onDate : getAllowed(myValidDates),
                }).datepick('setDate',myNewDates);
            }, 
        'json');            
    }); 
</script>
```

The issue is I want to submit the form (not via ajax) when a date is clicked. I found a bunch of posts but none of them seemed to work. If I un-comment that **"alert"** then I see the **"clicked"** message but neither the `$("#FormId").click(); (yes the form has a id="FormId" in it)` or `$(this).parent('form').submit();` or the 2 or 3 other ways I found to do the form submit.

I'm getting there on the click, the alert will fire if un-commented, how come the form won't submit?

(BTW - I didn't post the getAllowed function as I didn't think it relevant but I will if needed)

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the form an id and then calling submit via an jquery id selector:

```
<form id="myFormID">
...
$('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({
    multiSelect: 999,
    minDate : '-14d',
    maxDate : '+2y',                        
    onSelect : function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#myFormID').submit(); // <-- SUBMIT LIKE THIS
    },
    onDate : getAllowed(myValidDates),
}).datepick('setDate',myNewDates);
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tied .submit and it didn't work, but it did this time! Thanks!!

Comment: There is a more generic solution that doesn't require the form ID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041664/most-reusable-code-for-submit-on-select-with-jquery-datepicker