# Datepicker Submit form when select date

Tags: forms, datepicker, submit

please help me, how can i edit my javascript to submit form after select a date

```
     Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>


    <form action='?data=$data' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>

        <script>
      $(function() {
        $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ 'it' ] );
        $( '#locale' ).change(function() {
        $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker( 'option',
        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );

    });

  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found solution.
You may rewrite code like this.

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='formId'>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       onSelect : function (dateText, inst) {
          $('#formId').submit(); // <-- SUBMIT
  }});
});
```

This code from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133175/post-form-on-select-with-jquery-datepick)

Comment: There is a more generic solution that doesn't require the form ID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041664/most-reusable-code-for-submit-on-select-with-jquery-datepicker