# Datepicker click event should fire when a date is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is: When I click the a date on the date picker, a form on my page should get submitted.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: All that logic does is initializes the datepicker.

Comment: Have a look at the api documentation then and use the onafterpick or whatever method is fired after you pick a date

Comment: have you ever read documentation? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score -1):

This solution is working fine for me, Please try with this solution

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: See marked duplicate for the same code.

Comment: marked duplicate?

Comment: You add the same code from the answer of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171549/datepicker-submit-form-when-select-date