# Submit date with Foundation Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, zurb-foundation

Newbie in JS over here !

I got a slight problem to submit dates which one is selecting with the Foundation Datepicker from http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/ . I looked at the solutions already given on StackOverflow such as [Post form on select with JQuery Datepick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133175/post-form-on-select-with-jquery-datepick?lq=1) , but I was unable to find the one which is working in my case... So if a js expert can answer my question, I would be very grateful !

Here is my code:

```
<form id="SelectRealDate" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token%}
 <div class="row collapse date" id="dpMonths" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" data-start-view="year" data-min-view="year" style="max-width:200px;">
        <div class="small-2 columns">   
            <span class="prefix"><i class="fi-calendar" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="small-10 columns">
            <input size="16" type="text" value="02/2012" readonly>  
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dpMonths').fdatepicker({
 onSelect : function (dateText, inst) {
     console.log(5 + 6);
     $('#SelectRealDate').submit();
 }
});
</script>
```

The console.log is not really useful, I only wanted to see whether the onSelect was working or not. I really want to submit the date as it will be caught in a django view after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something similar to what the provided example page suggests:

```
$('#dpMonths').fdatepicker().on('changeDate', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#SelectRealDate').submit();
});
```